# Using WofE (weight of evidence) in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, flood

I need to use "weight of evidence" in a project about floodrisk

I heard that this model can be implemented in ArcMap but I did not find any videos in YouTube.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is a current tool for weight of evidence modeling in ArcGIS 10.x or ArcGIS Pro. A quick Google search found the following two pages, but not any obvious out of the box WOE tool.

1. [An article from 2000 about a WOE extension made for ArcView](https://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0400/files/wofe.pdf).
2. [A discussion about implementing WOE via python (in an ArcGIS setting)](https://community.esri.com/thread/217910-weight-of-evidence) with most recent comments from earlier this year.

I would encourage you to reach out to some of the authors and discussion participants about what they are currently using for tools.

And a more general piece of advice, when looking for ArcGIS solutions I would include doing a general web search (not just looking on YouTube) as there are a lot of non-video webpages that have great information. Tool documentation, text-based tutorials, and help pages like StackExchange.

Comment: Thanks  for your answer.
I read a lot of articles that used "arcgis"  like the file you posted. But unfortunately I did not find such a Toolbox